# Role Capabilities: Add New Ones?

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, capabilities

I'm trying to create a private type of community ... and the current `Capabilities` are great, except for the fact that I don't want users of a certain `Role` being able to see anything that someone else has created (posts, pages, etc)

I'd love to be able to create some new `Capabilities` that would compliment my application, such as: `view_others_posts` ... I just don't want a user of a specific `Role` to see anything except what they've created.

Another REALLY important example would be the Media Library ... I do NOT want users of a certain `Role` being able to see ANYTHING besides what they themselves have added to the Media Library. Make sense? ...for Admins, they can see all, but I need some serious private limits for users that belong to new custom `Role`

Are there any ways of doing so?

Comment: Did you manage to restrict the media library to certain roles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/) plugin allows you to create custom roles easily, and if you wish, change any standard WordPress user role (except administrator) as well. This plugin is very well maintained.

But just in case you haven't, I would like to suggest that you first consider reading about the various pre-defined Roles in WordPress and their capabilities — [WordPress Codex: Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).

**EDIT:** [Role Scoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/) allows you to assign restrictions and roles to specific pages, posts or categories.

Comment: Yes, I've used this Plugin before, and it's fantastic ... however, I'd like to avoid becoming dependant on any plugins. Besides, does it allow you to create new `Capabilities`?

Comment: Yes, the plugin's description clearly states that. And regarding `I'd like to avoid becoming dependant on any plugins` — some features are meant to be "plugged".

Comment: You can "create" a new capability, but once it's created, how is it connected to anything? It remains just a checkbox, on or off. There are no "rules" attached ... There's no way i'd be able to use this new Capability to affect whether or not a user can see content uploaded to the Media Gallery by other users...

Comment: @dcolumbus Hmm... makes sense. Did you try Role Scoper? (see answer edit) If that doesn't do what you want either (no media-specific features), you'll probably have to wait until someone chips in. :)

Comment: Role Scoper is a great addition... I let you know how it ends up working out. The issue is (and this is very typical of plugins) that I only need to address a few certain circumstances, not the kitchen sink.